# Did this "*variety* of ways" pun in the translation of Neukirch's ANT exist in the original German?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, translation-request

In Chapter I, $\S13.$ One-Dimensional Schemes of Neukirch's ANT, the first paragraph reads

> The first approach to the theory of algebraic number fields is dominated by the methods of arithmetic and algebra. But the theory may also be treated fundamentally from a geometric point of view, which will bring out novel aspects in a ***variety*** of ways.

Clearly, the translator intended for this pun, even though he did not write "pun intended". What I'm wondering is: did this pun exist in the original German version of ANT?

Comment: No, this paragraph does not make you chuckle in the german version. It reads as follows: "Die Theorie der algebraischen Zahlkörper, die zunächst von den Methoden der Arithmetik und der Algebra beherrscht wird, lässt sich in grundlegender Weise auch aus einer geometrischen Sicht behandeln, durch die sie auf vielfältige Art ganz neuartige Aspekte zeigt." Where "vielfätige" corresponds to variety, and has no mathematical meaning.

Comment: It could also just not be a pun, "in a variety of ways", "for a variety of purposes", etc. is fairly common and appear routinely in e.g. dictionary entries

Comment: Yes, I would not consider it an intentional pun also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bit "which will bring out novel aspects in a variety of ways" corresponds to
"durch die sie auf vielfältige Art ganz neue Aspekte zeigt."

There is no pun there. One could have made one,  using "mannigfaltige" instead of "vielfältige", which means about the same thing and would connect to "Mannigfaltigkeit", which means "manifold."